# Combine and split byte arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, base64, byte

I want to create methods like this:

```
public byte[] TransformStringsIntoBytes(string[] base64EncodedStrings)
{
  // I want to combine multiple base64 encoded strings to a byte array
  // but I want to have the possibility to convert it back to multiple strings
}

public string[] TransformBytesIntoStrings(string[] byteArray)
{
  // Here I want to convert the byte array back to the strings
}
```

So I want to combine multiple base64 encoded strings to a byte array, but I want to have the possibility to convert it back to multiple strings.
It is important that it is not a two dimensional byte array.
Maybe a possibility will be insert a delimiter after each string (is there a standard delimiter for bytes?)

Comment: You could length-prefix them? Use 2 or 4 bytes to contain the length of the byte array which follows.

Comment: If you have byte array, say `byte[] {1, 2, 3}` how can you determine if you have just one string (which corresponds to `{1, 2, 3}`), two (which correspond either to `{1, 2} {3}` or `{1} {2, 3}`) or three (`{1}`, `{2}`, `{3}`)?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko That is indeed what the question is asking. They suggest using a delimiter of some sort, but want to know what other options exist

Comment: `public string[] TransformBytesIntoStrings(string[] byteArray)` doesn't make sense. Shouldn't it be `public string[] TransformBytesIntoStrings(byte[] byteArray)`?

Comment: @canton7: I see; and if we have `64` distinct symbols within strings (since they are 64-base) we can easily find a delimiter within `256` distinct bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try exploiting the fact, that base**64** encoded string uses `64` different characters when ASCI one can use as many as `128` and byte has `256` distinct values. So we can use any symbol from Ascii (or `byte`) which is not among base 64 as a delimiter. In the code below, I use `\0` as such a delimiter:

```
public byte[] TransformStringsIntoBytes(string[] base64EncodedStrings) {
  if (base64EncodedStrings is null)
    return null;

  var result = new byte[base64EncodedStrings.Sum(array => array.Length) + 
                        base64EncodedStrings.Length - 1];

  for (int i = 0, index = 0; i < base64EncodedStrings.Length; ++i) {
    var array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(base64EncodedStrings[i]);

    if (i > 0)
      result[index++] = 0; // I use \0 as a delimiter

    Array.Copy(array, 0, result, index, array.Length);

    index += array.Length;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Reverse

```
public string[] TransformBytesIntoStrings(byte[] byteArray) {
  if (byteArray is null)
    return null;

  var result = new List<string>();

  for (int i = 0, index = 0; i < byteArray.Length; ++i)
    if (byteArray[i] == 0) { // I use \0 as a delimiter
      result.Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteArray.AsSpan(index, i - index)));

      index = i + 1;
    }
    else if (i == byteArray.Length - 1)
      result.Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteArray.AsSpan(index)));

  return result.ToArray();
}
```

Here I assumed that none of `base64EncodedStrings` items can be `null`.
If `null`s are possible, you have to encode them as well, e.g. as `\x0001` char:

```
public byte[] TransformStringsIntoBytes(string?[] base64EncodedStrings){
  if (base64EncodedStrings is null)
    return null;

  var result = new byte[base64EncodedStrings.Sum(array => (array ?? "\x0001").Length) +
                        base64EncodedStrings.Length - 1];

  for (int i = 0, index = 0; i < base64EncodedStrings.Length; ++i) {
    var array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(base64EncodedStrings[i] ?? "\x0001");

    if (i > 0)
      result[index++] = 0;

    Array.Copy(array, 0, result, index, array.Length);

    index += array.Length;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Reverse:

```
public string[] TransformBytesIntoStrings(byte[] byteArray) {
  if (byteArray is null)
    return null;

  var result = new List<string>();

  for (int i = 0, index = 0; i < byteArray.Length; ++i)
    if (byteArray[i] == 0) {
      string st = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteArray.AsSpan(index, i - index));

      result.Add(st == "\x0001" ? null : st);

      index = i + 1;
    }
    else if (i == byteArray.Length - 1) {
      string st = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteArray.AsSpan(index));

      result.Add(st == "\x0001" ? null : st);
    }

  return result.ToArray();
}
```